# Istio installation: Opening storage failed mkdir data/: permission denied

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

After running the install command for Istio via Helm,

I'm getting this:

```
My prometheus-f556886b8-96kjv                0/1       CrashLoopBackOff
```

if i run:

```
kubectl -n istio-system logs -f prometheus-f556886b8-96kjv
```

I see:

```
level=error ts=2019-01-22T04:15:25.485061247Z caller=main.go:597 err="Opening storage failed mkdir data/: permission denied"
```

Comment: How did you provision k8s cluster (Cloud provider, on-premise)? Can you describe Prometheus Pod: `kubectl describe pod prometheus-f556886b8-96kjv -n istio-system` ? Have you tried to check `data/` folder permissions: `kubectl exec -it prometheus-f556886b8-96kjv -n istio-system -- /bin/sh`?

Comment: I provisioned it on aws.  this is what the describe says:

Comment: Can you provide output of describe command? Have you checked required admission controllers on AWS as the official [guide](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/aws/) recommends?